# when I put a csv file in Sql Server with C #, some fields are written incorrectly?

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

Hi I have a problem with importing a csv file into a sql server, this csv file contains articles that need to be saved in the sql server database. Once the import (done with the code c # written below) is finished, some fields imported as (Descrizione and CodArt) are not written correctly in the database and have strange characters. To download the csv file [click here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/gbbnq56jnptugam/Bosch%20Luglio%202017.csv).

**SqlServer improper import over blue line:**
[image]

**Import C# Code:**

```
using (var rd = new StreamReader(labelPercorso.Text))
{
    Articolo a = new Articolo();
    a.db = this.db;

    while (!rd.EndOfStream)
    {
        //setto codean e immagine =null ad ogni giro 
        CodEAN = "";
        Immagine = "";

        try
        {
            var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(';');
            CodArt = splits[0];
            Descrizione = splits[1];
            String Price = splits[2];
            Prezzo = decimal.Parse(Price);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Non è presente nè immagine nè codean");
        }

        a.Prezzo = Prezzo;
        a.CodiceArticolo = CodArt;
        a.Descrizione = Descrizione;
        a.Fornitore = fornitore;
        //manca da controllare se l'articolo è presente e nel caso aggiornalo
        a.InserisciArticoloCSV();
    }
}
```

**Code of function: InserisciArticoloCSV**

```
try
{
    SqlConnection conn = db.apriconnessione();
    String query = "INSERT INTO Articolo(CodArt,Descrizione,Prezzo,PrezzoListino,Fornitore,Importato,TipoArticolo) VALUES(@CodArt,@Descrizione,@Prezzo,@PrezzoListino,@Fornitore,@Importato,@TipoArticolo)";
    String Importato = "CSV";
    String TipoArticolo = "A";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
   // MessageBox.Show("CodArt: " + CodiceArticolo + "\n Descrizione :" + Descrizione + "\n Prezzo: " + Prezzo);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodArt", CodiceArticolo.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descrizione", Descrizione.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prezzo", Prezzo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrezzoListino", Prezzo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fornitore", Fornitore.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Importato", Importato.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoArticolo", TipoArticolo.ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    db.chiudiconnessione();               
    conn.Close();

    return true;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Errore nell'inserimento dell'articolo " + ex);
    //MessageBox.Show("Errore nel inserimento dell'articolo:  " + ex);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I believe it would be something with  csv encoding vs DB collation

Comment: @apomene I also tried to save it with the unicode standard but it does not change anything

Comment: Unfortunately my company blocks the site you put the csv on - as a whole offsite links are generally not preferred anyway can you not show some example (minimal viable etc) including data here?

Comment: Isn't this the case that some of your descriptions contain line breaks? which split up rows in csvs?

Comment: @user6144226 I've already tried removing csv (;) delimiters from the file before loading it but it does not load anyway

Comment: @RiccardoPirani - not what I meant -since you are using readline() having a linebreak inside your last attribute (descprizone) breaks your reader.

Comment: You should specify the correct encoding when you read your file. Is it `utf`? Is it ascii with a specific code page? You should also specify the SqlDbType of your Sql parameters, especially the string parameters which will be either varchar or nvarchar and there is a big difference between them.

Comment: Honestly I did not think so, I read on wikipedia that for csv is not defined a unique standard and in windows is the default ASCII character used, how can i specify the import of the file format type? @igor

Comment: @RiccardoPirani - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you have numerous problems, encoding, carriage returns and a lot of white space.  In addition you are using single inserts into your database, which is very slow.  I show below some sample code, which illustrates how to deal with all of these points.

```
IFormatProvider fP = new CultureInfo("it");
DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
tmp.Columns.Add("CodArt", typeof(string));
tmp.Columns.Add("Descrizione", typeof(string));
tmp.Columns.Add("Prezzo", typeof(decimal));
using (var rd = new StreamReader("yourFileName", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    while (!rd.EndOfStream)
    {
        try
        {
            var nextLine = Regex.Replace(rd.ReadLine(), @"\s+", " ");
            while (nextLine.Split(';').Length < 3)
            {
                nextLine = nextLine.Replace("\r\n", "") + Regex.Replace(rd.ReadLine(), @"\s+", " ");
            }
            var splits = nextLine.Split(';');
            DataRow dR = tmp.NewRow();
            dR[0] = splits[0];
            dR[1] = splits[1];
            string Price = splits[2];
            dR[2] = decimal.Parse(Price, fP);
            tmp.Rows.Add(dR);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

using (var conn = db.apriconnessione())
{
    var sBC = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
    conn.Open();
    sBC.DestinationTableName = "yourTableName";
    sBC.WriteToServer(tmp);
    conn.Close();
}
```

Now for some explanation:

Firstly I am storing the parsed values in a DataTable.  Please note that I have only included the three fields that are in the CSV.  In practice you must supply the other columns and fill the extra columns with the correct values for each row.  I was simply being lazy, but I am sure you will get the idea.

I do not know what encoding your csv file is, but `iso-8859-1` worked for me!

I use Regex to replace multiple white space with a single space.

If any line does not have the required number of splits, I keep adding further lines (having deleted the carriage return) until I hit success!

Once I have a complete line, I can now split it, and assign it to the new DataRow (please see my comments above for extra columns).

Finally once the file has been read, the DataTable will have all the rows and can be uploaded to your database using BulkCopy.  This is very fast!

HTH

PS Some of your lines have double quotes.  You probably want to get rid of these as well!

Comment: perfect It works perfectly thanks, I just wanted to remove the double quotes !! If I find you in the street, I offered you a coffee

Comment: @RiccardoPirani  My pleasure, but I'd prefer a beer!

Answer (score 2):

Your CSV file is not well formated , there are intermediatory Carriage Returns in between , which screws up the parsing. See the file in Notepad++ and turn on the Line Breaks , this is what you find.

[image: Format Issue]

So for the lines which are in format the data import is working fine , for others the logic is not working.

Comment: the column is nvarchar (4000), even with your code I always import the file incorrectly

Comment: Nice find (+1), that will wreck the OP's code for sure.

Comment: This file is passed by a person who converts an excel file to csv with office excel, how can i get it because it is converted from excel files to csv files without this error? @Igor

Comment: @RiccardoPirani - 1) This is not my answer. 2) The excel column's values also has line breaks, you need to figure out how to read the CSV with line breaks or find an off the shelf CSV parser that can (there are many free tools available just search nuget). Alternatively you can read the Excel instead of CSV.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the correct encoding when you read your file. Is it utf? Is it ascii with a specific code page? You should also specify the SqlDbType of your Sql parameters, especially the string parameters which will be either varchar or nvarchar and there is a big difference between them.

```
// what is the encoding of your file? This is an example using code page windows-1252
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
using (var file = File.Open(labelPercorso.Text, FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file, encoding))
{
  // rest of code unchanged
}
```

Sql Code. Note that I added `using` blocks for the types that implement `IDisposable` like Connection and Command.

```
try
{
    String query = "INSERT INTO Articolo(CodArt,Descrizione,Prezzo,PrezzoListino,Fornitore,Importato,TipoArticolo) VALUES(@CodArt,@Descrizione,@Prezzo,@PrezzoListino,@Fornitore,@Importato,@TipoArticolo)";
    String Importato = "CSV";
    String TipoArticolo = "A";

    using(SqlConnection conn = db.apriconnessione())
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        // -1 indicates you used MAX like nvarchar(max), otherwise use the maximum number of characters in the schema
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlDbParameter("@CodArt", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1)).Value = CodiceArticolo.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlDbParameter("@Descrizione", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1)).Value = Descrizione.ToString();

        /*
          Rest of your parameters created in the same manner
        */

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        db.chiudiconnessione();               
    }
    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Errore nell'inserimento dell'articolo " + ex);
    //MessageBox.Show("Errore nel inserimento dell'articolo:  " + ex);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: then I went up the UTF-8 encoding file! I changed GetEncoding with UTF-8 and tried to import it with your code but I always get the same error

Comment: @RiccardoPirani - see what `SoumenMukherjee` wrote, you have to take the line breaks into consideration in your code. Also I never said/wrote/hinteded you have to use UTF-8, likely the file is ASCII but with a specific code page and you need to figure out what that code page is and use that for your encoding so it can be read correctly.

Comment: I saw it now, what he wrote @igor

Comment: @RiccardoPirani - I do not understand your last comment?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you are interested in exploring library to handle all parsing needs with few lines of code, you can check out the [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library. Here is sample to parse the csv file and shows how to get either datatable or list of records for later to load them to database.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("it");

using (var p = new ChoCSVReader("Bosch Luglio 2017.csv")
    .Configure((c) => c.MayContainEOLInData = true) //Handle newline chars in data
    .Configure(c => c.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")) //Specify the encoding for reading
    .WithField("CodArt", 1) //first column
    .WithField("Descrizione", 2) //second column
    .WithField("Prezzo", 3, fieldType: typeof(decimal)) //third column
    .Setup(c => c.BeforeRecordLoad += (o, e) =>
    {
        e.Source = e.Source.CastTo<string>().Replace(@"""", String.Empty); //Remove the quotes
    }) //Scrub the data
    )
{
    var dt = p.AsDataTable();

    //foreach (var rec in p)
    //    Console.WriteLine(rec.Prezzo);
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.